# Do not track changes to a config file

Tags: svn

I have a repository with a config.mk file. This file belongs in the repository. However I would like to check this repository out and use in multiple places (by multiple people) and don't want everyone to commit their changes to config.mk.

Basically when I do an `svn commit` I don't want it to check for changes in config.mk. I don't *think* ignore is the right property for this but I'm not sure and couldn't find an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The svn ignore only works for files that do not belong to your repository.  If the file is needed in the repo for CICD or audit activities, and you want developers to maintain their own config.mk file in their workspace without SVN seeing their changes during commit, you need to add a *deny access* rule for the file.

Next, have the developers add the file to their ignore list.

Third, add a check to the repository's pre-commit hook to prevent users from attempting to add their version of this file to the repo.

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`findstr /E /I /R "config.mk" %TEMP%\%reposname%_%rev%_tempfile%2`) do (
  echo The config.mk is not allowed for commit >&2
  exit /b 1
)
```